# Gulp: how to rename files from *.config.disabled to *.config in the same directory

Tags: gulp

I'm attempting to use a gulp task using `gulp-rename` to rename all `.Azure.config.disabled` files to be `.Azure.config` files.

My code is:

```
return gulp
    .src("C:\\Temp\\CD\\App_Config\\Include\\{Feature,Foundation,Project}\\**\\*.*Azure.config.disabled")
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.extname = ".config"
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return gulp
    .src("C:\\Temp\\CD\\App_Config\\Include\\{Feature,Foundation,Project}\\**\\*.*Azure.config.disabled")
    .pipe(rename(function (path) {
        path.dirname = config.packagePath + "\\CD\\App_Config\\Include\\" + path.dirname;
        path.basename = path.basename.replace('.config', '');
        path.extname = ".config";
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

Basically, the `dirname` is set to the folder name of each file, not the entire path of the directory. `Gulp.dest(".")` was "C:\Temp", so it would output to "C:\Temp\Feature" rather than the actual path the file was in.